# Validate checkbox not mapped to entity in a symfony2 form

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, checkbox

I add a non mapped field to a symfony2 form type:

```
$builder->add('terms','checkbox', array('mapped' => false,
        'constraints' => array(new NotBlank())));
```

But the NotBlank() constraint is not working! Only if I change the type from 'checkbox' to 'text' it is working as expected. So how can I validate a checkbox? Of course I tried with 'True()', 'EqualTo()' and 'Length(...)' constraints too. But without success. I also tried different POST values (1/0, true/false, on/off...) for the field.

What is the big difference between a checkbox field and a text field regarding form field validation in symfony2?

Thanx
Stef

Comment: To get eyes on your question, you should tag it with the most popular tag that is relevant to your question - in this case, I would recommending replacing one of your tags, like the 'constraints' tag with 'PHP'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`NotBlank` validates string to be not empty. Try to use `NotNull`

[IsTrue](https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/reference/constraints/IsTrue.html) must also works.

> Validates that a value is true. Specifically, this checks to see if
> the value is exactly true, exactly the integer 1, or exactly the
> string "1". This constraint can be applied to properties (e.g. a termsAccepted property on a registration model).

Comment: [True](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/True.html) works for me to validate checkbox, thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Updated answer for **Symfony 3.0+:**

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue;

// ...
{
    $builder->add('terms', CheckboxType::class, array('constraints'=>new IsTrue(array('message'=>'Needs to be clicked')));
}
```